# Building VB6 Projects in TFS 2010 - correct approach?

Tags: vb6, msbuild, vb6-migration

I've been fiddling with setting up automated builds for our old VB6 COM components.

I have successfully installed the MSSCCI provider for TFS 2010 and can successfully check in and check out code from the repository in the Visual Basic IDE.

My repository consists of 1 Team Project (called VB6) with separate directories for each VB6 project.

I'd like to be able to build all the VB6 projects in the Team Project when someone checks in any changes on any of the VB6 projects (I'm sure I can do this by setting up multiple builds in the build definition).

As far as I can tell, there are 2 ways to get this to work:
[Editing the Build Template](http://www.richard-banks.org/2010/08/how-to-build-vb6-apps-with-tfs-team.html) or using the [MSBuild Extension Pack](http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/)

1. Will both of these require me to install the VB6 compiler on the build machine?
2. Which is the preferred approach for TFS 2010, MSBuild v4?

I prefer the idea of editing the build template than having to install the extension pack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MSBuild .proj files have been superseeded by windows workflow XAML build templates in VS2010 so I would go with that approach. As far as I know, either way you will have to install Visual Basic on the server as you need the old VB6 compiler.

Comment: +1. You will need the VB6 compiler. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444505/what-are-the-command-line-options-for-the-vb6-ide-compiler) lists the command-line args for the compiler. There are [also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179099/buildprocess-for-activex-com-vb6-enterprise-projects) [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160881/vb6-integration-with-msbuild) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226730/using-nant-and-ivy-to-build-a-vb6-project) about automatic builds with VB6. They are well worth a look